# Sunni authenticity of this quote about zulfiqar

Tags: halal-haram, authenticity, shia-sunni, ali, battles

There is a saying attributed to the Prophet during the Battle of Uhud:

> فتى إلا علي لا سيف إلا ذو الفقار‎ لا
>
> 'There is no hero like Ali; There is no sword like Dhu-l-Fiqar'

Now the Shia say it was said by archangel Jibril/a voice on the battlefield etc (something along those lines, correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is what is the Sunni view on the authenticity of this quote, because the Ottoman Janissaries had this quote on their flags and they were Sunni.

Also is it permissible to wear a zulfiqar (for a Sunni)? Not trying to mimic the Shia or Alevi.

Answer (score 1):

This narration is not considered very authentic by Sunnis.

Ibn Jawzi quotes it in his book Mawdhoo'aat ("Fabrications"), so that should give an indication. He goes on to quote the narrations and claimed chains for it and shows how they are weak.

I could also mention the comments of other scholars and their weakening of the narrations, but that might be too long.

It should also be noted that Sunnis and Shias have a very distinct difference in hadith sciences: they disagree on whom the chain needs to end at.

The Shias consider the narration authentic as long as it ends at one of the infallible Imams.

Sunnis do not believe in any infallible people after the Prophet, so a report is only truly authentic if it ends at someone who witnessed the event, and a law or statement is only binding when it ends at the Prophet (SAW).

If a report ends at one of the Imams of the Shia, such a report would just be mursal i.e. disconnected and would be taken as the opinions or views of the Imam (who might be to us a great scholar but not infallible) like all opinions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no youth but Ali, there is no sword but Zulfiqar" In Sunni sources..”
I swear by God, do you know that among the emigrants and Ansar, except Gabriel, no one was sent down to say, O Muhammad, there is no sword like Zulfiqar and no gentleman like Ali; Among the emigrants and Ansar, Gabriel has given such an interpretation to someone ?! They said: No. History of the city of Damascus and mentioning its virtues and naming them from their proverbs, author's name: Abi Al-Qasim Ali Ibn Al-Hassan Ibn Hiba Allah Ibn Abdullah Al-Shafi'i, Publisher: Dar Al-Fikr - Beirut – 1995. ، 201p.
The Holy Prophet said: He is from me and I am from him and Gabriel said: I am also from you. Then they heard a voice from heaven saying: A sword is none other than Zulfiqar and chivalry is none other than Ali. Tarikh al-Tabari, author's name: Labi Ja'far Muhammad ibn Jarir al-Tabari, publisher: Dar al-Kitab al-Almiya - Beirut, vol. 2, p. 65

Answer (score -2):

Documents of Hadith There is no youth but Ali, no sword but Zulfiqar
The opinion of the Shiite scholars is that Gabriel shouted  in the sky (la fata ela Ali La sayf ala zolfaghar) "There is no youth but Ali, no sword but Zulfiqar " لا فتی الا علی لا سیف الا ذوالفقار
and the Holy Prophet said that this is the voice of Gabriel.

1-  Tabari has quoted this narration from Abi Rafi on page 17 of the third volume of history: On the day of Uhud, when Ali (AS) killed the flag bearers of the Quraysh army and threw them to the ground, the Messenger of God saw some of the Quraysh polytheists and ordered Ali to attack them. The Imam attacked them and dispersed them. Killed, then Gabriel said: O Messenger of God, this is the meaning of equality and brotherhood. The Prophet said: Ali is from me and I am from him. Gabriel said: I am one of you. Abi Rafi says: At this time, people heard a voice that said: La Fati illa Ali La Saif al Zulfiqar. (There is no youth but Ali, no sword but Zulfiqar).

2- This narration has been narrated by Ahmad ibn Hanbal from Ibn Abbas in the book "Al-Fadha'il".

3- Ibn Hisham in the third volume of Sira, p. 152, has narrated this process from Ibn Abi Najih.

4- Khathami in "Al-Rawd Al-Anf", Volume 2, page 143.

5- Ibn Abi Al-Hadid has quoted this narration in "Sharh al-Nahj", volume one, page 9, and says that this narration is famous, and in the second volume, page 236, he says that when the Messenger of God (PBUH) heard this voice, he said: . This narration is also given in vol. 3, p. 281.

6- Kharazmi narrates from Muhammad ibn Ishaq ibn Yasar in “Al-Manaqib” p. There is no safe except for Zulfiqar, except for Ali There is no sword except Zulfiqar and the young man is no other than Ali. فذا ندبتم هلکا فابکوا الوفی اخا الوفی Whenever you want to cry over a dead person, cry over a faithful man who is a faithful brother.

7- Hamoui has narrated the same thing about his forty-ninth chapter and has brought the chain of documents to his documents from Hafiz Bayhaqi to Ali ibn Abi Talib in various ways.:

There is a Betty in Yemen who is covered in iron. Send someone to smash and crush it and record its iron. Ali (AS) says that when Gabriel gave this order to the Holy Prophet (PBUH), the Prophet summoned me and gave me this mission. I smashed the idol and took the iron and brought it to the Prophet. I made two swords out of it. I called him Zulfiqar and I called him another. The Prophet fell on me and said: There is no sword except Zulfiqar and no youth except Ali.

Amini says: Numerous hadiths that have been narrated in this regard inform us that the process took place several times and the preacher on the day of Uhud was Gabriel, but the preacher on the day of Badr was another king named Rezvan and the leaders of the science of hadith agree on quoting this story. Ganji claimed consensus and quoted his book Kefaya on page 144 through Abi al-Ghanaim, and Ibn Jawzi, and Salafi, Ibn al-Jawaliqi, and Ibn Abi al-Wafa Baghdadi, Ibn al-Walid, Ibn Abi al-Fahm, Mufti Abdul Karim Mosul, Muhammad ibn Qasim Adl, Hafiz Muhammad ibn Mahmud Ibn Abi al-Badr, Faqih Abdul Ghani ibn Ahmad, Sadiqah ibn al-Husayn Yusuf ibn Sherwan Muqari, Sahib ibn Abi al-Ma'ali Dawami, Ibn Battah, Sheikh al-Shaykh Abdul Rahman ibn al-Latif, Ali ibn Muhammad al-Muqari, Ibn Bakrous, Hafiz ibn al-Ma'ali and Abi Abdullah Muhammad ibn Umar according to their documents from Sa'd ibn Tarif Hanzali from Abi Ja'far Muhammad ibn Ali al-Baqir (AS) who said:

On the day of Badr, a king whose name was Rezwan shouted: There is no sword except Zulfiqar and no Youth except Ali
Then Amini says: I said that the leaders of the science of hadith have agreed on quoting this part of the story and narration, and the elders have quoted from each other, just as we thank God for the hadith as a pleasant blue in the best way and in the best way of many documents. I collapsed and we brought it in our book. This narration has been narrated by the ruler in detail and Bayhaqi has examined it in "Manaqib" in the chain of documents and has quoted it from the ruler and says: This narration was narrated by Hafiz Ibn Najjar and he told us from Tusi from Jabir ibn Abdullah that the Prophet in On the day of the Battle of Badr, he said: This is Rezvan, who is an angel of God, and they called: There is no sword except for Zulfiqar and no youth other than Ali.

Moheb al-Din al-Tabari has narrated the narration with the same words on page 190 of "Riyadh" and page 74 of Al-Aqbi reserves. Kharazmi has quoted Jabir's hadith on page 101 of Manaqib. And Nasr ibn Mazahim narrated on page 257 of Safin book (published in Egypt, p. 546 by Jabir ibn Namir (Sahih is Umayr) Ansari: who says: I heard from the Messenger of God (PBUH) who reads this verse many times: There is no sword except Zulfiqar and no youth other than Ali. Al-Ghadir in the Book,(Al-Ghadir fel ketab) Sunnah and Literature(  Al Adab), vol. 2, pp. 102 to 105.

Comment: After going through the more than 300 narratives related to 'Ali ibn abi Talib in imam Ahmad's al-Fadail I couldn't find/locate it (even if the book has a lot of doubtful narratives). However you may find in the whole book 4 times a mentioning of "youth فتى" one of them referring to Khalid ibn al-Walid and in al-Musnad one time the mentioning of the prophet's () sword Dhu al-Fiqar in which he reported of a dream and his interpretation this was reported on the authority of ibn 'Abbas. I know that shi'a claim it is in this book, but in other sources they made clearer references.